# mysqlclient.whl is not supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install `mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl` that I have saved to local drive. I am using:

`pip 21.2.3 Python 3.10.0` 
when I run:

`pip install mysqlclient mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`

I get this error:

`ERROR: mysqlclient-1.3.13-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I would like to know what the problem is?

Comment: See if you understand and solve it with this:

https://scottontechnology.com/solved-is-not-a-supported-wheel-on-this-platform/

Comment: @jollibobert I have already tried it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqlclient‑1.3.13‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl`

It's a wheel intended for CPython 3.4. You have CPython 3.10. Either use Python 3.4 or get a wheel for Python 3.10.

PS. You've upgraded to Python 3.10 [too early](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/switch-python-3.10/). My advice is to use Python 3.9 and get a wheel for it.